# OAuth 1.0a 'one-legged' authentication with Objective-C causing Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, oauth, woocommerce

I am trying to make a GET request with OAuth 1.0a one-legged authentication to the WooCommerce REST-API but I am struggling. I am attempting to generate my signature like so but all I receive is invalid signature. Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

```
- (void)generateURL
{
NSString *apiURL = @"http://www.example.com/wc-api/v2/orders";
NSString *oauth_consumer_key = @"ck_example";
NSString *oauth_nonce = @"32charstring";
NSString *oauth_signature_method = @"HMAC-SHA1";
NSString *oauth_timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

NSString *encodedApiURL = urlformdata_encode(apiURL);

NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=%@&oauth_nonce=%@&oauth_signature_method=%@&oauth_timestamp=%@", oauth_consumer_key, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_timestamp, nil];
NSString *encodedParameters = urlformdata_encode(parameters);

NSString *signature = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GET&%@&%@", encodedApiURL, encodedParameters];
signature = [self hmacsha1:signature secret:@"cs_example"];

NSString *finalUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@&oauth_signature=%@", apiURL, parameters, signature, nil];
NSLog(@"Final URL: %@", finalUrl);
}

- (NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)data secret:(NSString *)key {

const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedString];

return hash;
}

static NSString* urlformdata_encode(NSString* s) {
return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                           NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)s,
                                                           NULL,
                                                           (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                           kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding the secret key, to get the signature, append an unencoded & at the end of the secret key(cs_key&). This seemed to work for me. I am using v3 of the WooCommerce API

Comment: So in my example would the following be appropriate? cs_example&

Comment: Well, OAuth problems were fixed in the v3 version of the WooCommerce API call. And, I have used almost the same code for v2 and it seemed to work perfectly and adding the "&" for v3 worked too